# Replace the XML element with new Element in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xslt-2.0, xquery-sql

Replace `<apipAccessbility>` element of this content with a new element in multiple rows with a column of type `XML`:

```
<Item title="1234" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2">
    <ItemBody>xyz</ItemBody>
    <apipAccessibility xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/apip/apipv1p0/imsapip_qtiv1p0">
        <accessibilityInfo>
        Blablah
        </accessibilityInfo>
    </apipAccessibility>
</Item>
```

Once element is updated it should look like this:

```
<Item title="1234" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2">
    <ItemBody>xyz</ItemBody>
    <apipAccessibility xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/apip/apipv1p0/imsapip_qtiv1p0"/>
</Item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`modify`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093.aspx) and [`delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190254.aspx):

```
UPDATE tab
SET col.modify('
  declare namespace NS="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2";
  declare namespace NS2="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/apip/apipv1p0/imsapip_qtiv1p0";
  delete /NS:Item/NS2:apipAccessibility/*')
-- WHERE id = 1;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/447174?opt.textResults=true)**</kbd>

Output:

```
<Item xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2" title="1234">
  <ItemBody>xyz</ItemBody>
  <apipAccessibility xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/apip/apipv1p0/imsapip_qtiv1p0" />
</Item>
```