# Replace XML Span Element with Inner text of Span Tag in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xquery-sql

Replace span Element with its inner text  whose class is "TAGGED_ITEM " in multiple rows with a column of type XML

```
    <Item title="1234" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2">
        <ItemBody>
        <div class="item_text">
                        <div>
                            <span class="TAGGED_ITEM " id="c1_ae1">This is a map on a grid.</span>
                            <span class="TAGGED_ITEM " id="c1_ae2"> It shows a car.</span>
                        </div>
<span class="TAGGED_ITEM " id="c1_ae3"> It shows a car on Road.</span>
                    </div>
        </ItemBody>
    </Item>
```

Once Element is updated it should looks as below.

```
<Item title="1234" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2">
        <ItemBody>
        <div class="item_text">
                        <div>
                            This is a map on a grid.
                             It shows a car.
                        </div>
                           It shows a car on Road.
                    </div>
        </ItemBody>
    </Item>
```

Comment: You've [already asked (and gotten answers!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873792/replace-the-xml-element-with-new-element-in-sql-server) pretty much the same question before - how is this different? Please - **do not** ask the basically same question over and over and over again !

Comment: @marc_s this question is different from previous question. Here I am looking for replacing specific existing Span Elements which has class attribute value "TAGGED_ITEM " with its oven inner text. Completely different from previous question.

Answer (score 1):

This question had a particular namespace problem which, probably, had aroused the question. Eliminating namespaces on the `match=` does solve the problem. So an identity transform and a namespace-neutral matching gives the desired result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'span']">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
  </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Item xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2" title="1234">
    <ItemBody>
    <div class="item_text">
                    <div>
                        This is a map on a grid.
                         It shows a car.
                    </div>
                </div>
    </ItemBody>
</Item>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer ,but I am looking for Sql Query in solving it.

Comment: @Chatrapathi: Ok. Posted it, because you had the `XSLT` tag on it. I see you got it removed by now. No prob.